# How to do single sign on between an asp.net application and existing sharepoint web application which is claims enabled

Tags: 2013, asp.net, adfs, security-token-service, single-sign-on

I want to implement single sign on between an asp.net application  and an existing SharePoint web application which is claims authentication enabled.

1. asp.net application is  farm authentication enabled and it
   authenticate users from sql server database.
2. i created a custom STS service using asp.net security token service
   application using [windows identity foundation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff955607%28v=office.14%29#sp14ClaimsExample1_OverviewofTrustedLoginProvider) in `customsecuritytokenservicce` class  methods in `GetOutputClaimsIdentity` i added email `outputIdentity.Claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email , "adil@test.com"));`
   to issue email claim

3. i added sts reference to asp.net application
4. the same sts i registered using powershell to my sharepoint web application

   $cert=New-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("C:\SPPROJECTS\STS\stscert.cer")
   $map1 = New-SPClaimTypeMapping -IncomingClaimType "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "EmailAddress" -SameAsIncoming
   $map2 = New-SPClaimTypeMapping -IncomingClaimType "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "Role" -SameAsIncoming
   $realm = "http://sp2010/_trust/default.aspx"
   $ap=New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer -Name "STSPRO" -Description "Our Fancy CustomSTS" -Realm $realm -ClaimsMappings $map1,$map2 -ImportTrustCertificate $cert  -SignInUrl "https://localhost:96/login.aspx" -IdentifierClaim $map1.InputClaimType
   New-SPTrustedRootAuthority -Name "sp2010" -Certificate $cert

now when i open sharepoint site it shows two authenction opetions to login to sharepoint site, when i login using customsts i able to login to sharepoint site and
it shows adil@test.com user , before that i added this user in sharepoint as administrator.

Now here

1. How to wirte code the custom sts can validate user from sql server
2. how i do or implement single sign on from asp.net to sharepoint site

when user authenticated to asp.net application and when user goes to sharepoint site from asp.net it would not ask authentication

Comment: check this one https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8269e8d3-488a-462c-8d23-7684f1360e95/single-sign-on-between-sharepoint-2010-net-web-application?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious